# Binary Search Tree - Access Violation

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

This method finds the largest node in a BST returns its value and deletes it. I am getting an access violation at `prev->rightLink = cur->leftLink;`.  I am relatively unfamiliar with C++ and not able to find the cause.

```
int CTree::popLargest(TreeNode* tr)
{   
    int largest;
    TreeNode* prev = NULL;
    TreeNode* cur = tr;

    while (cur->rightLink != NULL)
    {
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->rightLink;
        largest = cur->info;
        //DeleteAttemptTwo(tr, largest);//DeleteItem(largest);     
    }

    if (cur->leftLink != NULL)
    {
        prev->rightLink = cur->leftLink;
    }
    else 
    {
        prev->rightLink = NULL;
    }

    return largest;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This if and else makes little sense -

```
if (cur->leftLink != NULL)
{
    prev->rightLink = cur->leftLink;
}
else 
{
    prev->rightLink = NULL;
}
```

What you are trying to do can be done just by - `prev->rightLink = cur->leftLink;`

And the reason you are getting access violation on this statement is that `prev` is not pointing to a valid node, which is when it is `NULL` (as initialized).

Answer (score 1):

In case when tree wouldn't have any right child, prev will remain null and while executing

```
prev->rightLink = cur->leftLink;
```

you are trying to access property of null variable, hence 'Access Voilation'.

Answer (score 1):

The cause is that prev is still NULL. You should verify if a pointer is NULL when you dereference it.BTW, this question is easy to find by debugging.

```
const int INVALID_VALUE = -1;    // change it by yourself.
int CTree::popLargest(TreeNode* tr)
{  
    int largest = INVALID_VALUE;
    if (tr != NULL)
    {
        TreeNode* prev = NULL;
        TreeNode* cur = tr;
        while (cur->rightLink != NULL)
        {
            prev = cur;
            cur = cur->rightLink;
            largest = cur->info;
            //DeleteAttemptTwo(tr, largest);//DeleteItem(largest);     
        }
        if (prev != NULL)
        {
            if (cur->leftLink != NULL)
            {
                prev->rightLink = cur->leftLink;
            }
            else 
            {
                prev->rightLink = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not taking into account the case where `tr` has no right elements (`tr->rightLink = NULL`, `cur = tr`), and therefore the contents of the `while` loop never execute. In that case, `prev` remains as `NULL`, which means you're then trying to dereference `NULL` when trying to access the `rightLink` element of `prev`.

Trying to dereference `NULL` will lead to some sort of access violation error.